# What is the word for thinking a joke is both funny and bad (groan-worthy) at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English that describes the feeling or thinking that a joke is funny, but really bad (i.e. groan-worthy) at the same time? For example, most puns cause many people to groan, but they might also make the same people laugh momentarily ("It's not that the man did not know how to juggle; he just didn't have the balls to do it.").

If not that, is there a word that describes such a joke?

Comment: "groan-worthy" is perfect!

Comment: The ball-less juggler was a nice example!

Comment: No, no, no. They're not *groan* -worthy, they're **thwack** -worthy. Get your terminology straight, peoples!

Comment: @Martha +1 Agreed, immanently thwackable.

Comment: In India, we use PJ for such jokes. I think, it stands for poor joke, but nobody is sure now. Some newspapers even have columns titled PJs for such jokes.

Comment: @rest - fascinating!

Answer (score 7):

Such jokes are generally described as either "cheesy" or "corny".

Comment: Absolutely. Although as others have pointed out, OP's own *groan-worthy* is prefectly okay - not to mention being a bit more snappy and modern.

Answer (score 4):

I think *groan-worthy* is fine.  If you find that's a bit unwieldy, the classic choice would be *corny*.  For jokes that rely on puns, *punny* seems to be gaining currency.

Answer (score 2):

I think the normal slang term is "cheesy".

Answer (score 1):

here, we use the word `dry` in colloquial responses to joking. one might have read of a `dry sense of humor` ie. a joke delivered in deadpan or emotionlessly. usually to characterise someone in general, than a compliment to either person or joke. it can go either way.

so "dry" as a standalone response would be better than `cheesy`/`corny` (sappy/cliche) but `groan-worthy`/`lame` (ridiculous) enough to warrant any of: a dry/awkward/sarcastic/disbelieving laugh, a non-response, confusion or genuine laughter followed/backed by the term.

And because they havent been said yet -- what about `dumb`, `punny` or `criiinge-worthy`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the term:

> Lame joke

They're like jokes that cause you to laugh for a moment, and then you groan, "oh, not again!", and then have a teeny bit of exasperation feeling.

Comment: One has to be a bit careful with *lame*. I don't use the word myself, but my general impression of people that do is they are.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am unusual in that, if I think a joke is bad, I tend not to laugh. Groan worthy jokes are still funny, but also groan-worthy. Cheesy comes close I would say, or a Groaner. Bad implies that is not a good joke, which by definition it must be if it made you laugh. Same for Lame joke. That said, in the court of public opinion, we even have books devoted to bad jokes, which I am sure, many people laugh at. I just can't call a joke that actually manages to amuse me, a bad joke.

Answer (score 0):

Corny

That's the word we used growing up.

Comment: Hello, user149431, and welcome to English Language & Usage. "Corny" is a very apt word to suggest, in my opinion—but to distinguish your answer from the one that rintaun submitted four years ago (suggesting both "corny" and "cheesy"), you might consider adding a relevant dictionary definition for the word _corny_ to your answer. Doing so would also help readers who may not be familiar with the term in this sense see more readily why your suggestion is a good one. Thanks!

Comment: @SvenYargs Thanks for the tip. Still learning the platform.